# MongoDb Shell in Nodejs Environment

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDb along with Nodejs, Express and Atom editor.  I am also using mLab hosting for the database.  I'd like to be able to access the shell so I can perform queries by experimentation, etc.  I am not sure if a separate installation of something is necessary or what.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongo shell is accessible by using the cli command mongo, it should have installed with mongodb especially if you used a package manager; like brew, if you are on mac. If you are on windows I believe you have to add an .exe extension in order to execute the shell. If the shell is not starting check your $PATH variable and make sure a path was created to the installation directory. 
One thing to note is that you need to specify the server url and options which should be available from the MLab site: http://docs.mlab.com/
Once you have a connection through the mongo cli you should be able to perform operations on the database. The first step is to enable roles on the databases you plan on working with or else you will get an error when trying to read and write to databases.
Once you have connected to the server you still have to create an admin user with root privileges in order to read and write to any database. You can also set specific permissions on a case by case basis per database. Here is a link that should help point you in the right direction :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/

Comment: I see no reference to Mongo in my path.  Also, I think all I did was npm -install mongodb.  I did not install anything else.   I have mLab db all set up and working.  Where to from here?

Comment: You need to go to the mongo db site and download the mongodb program all the node install is, is a driver for writing programs that connect to a mongodb instance; you have to actually download the community server and the cli interface comes bundled with it. If you are using Mac I suggest using brew. If not Mac then download the version that you require. Here is the link: <https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community>

Comment: I must note that mongodb is good and it's nice that it is written with JavaScript in mind. Configuring it to be accessible to read and write to takes a little time to learn. Mlab gives pretty good documentation on how to connect, then commands are executable through the cli. <http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#users>